# Kotlin coroutines hanging for several minutes

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, parallel-processing, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

While practicing and learnign Kotlin I benchmarked several methods for launching parallel workers. In the `when` statement option `4` sometimes hangs partway through computing `benchedVals` and CPU usage drops to 0%. After a couple minutes computation resumes. Option `5` never hangs this way, the children complete their work after a few seconds while the main thread waits and then the main thread resumes.

I am not sure what the difference is between these that causes one to hang but not the other.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.measureTime

@ExperimentalTime
fun run(toRun: Int, totalParallel: Long = 10_000_000L): Pair<Duration, Long> {
    val c = AtomicLong()
    val time = measureTime {
        when (toRun) {
            4 -> {
                val deferred = (1..totalParallel).map { i ->
                    GlobalScope.async {
                        c.addAndGet(i)
                    }
                }
                runBlocking {
                    deferred.map { it.await() }
                }
            }
            5 -> {
                val workers = GlobalScope.launch {
                    for (i in 1..totalParallel) {
                        launch {
                            c.addAndGet(i)
                        }
                    }
                }
                runBlocking { workers.join() }
            }
        }

    }
    return Pair(time, c.get())
}

@ExperimentalTime
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val benchedVals = (0 until 1000).map { println(it); run(4, 1000).first }
}
```

Comment: 4 launches the coroutines and awaits on their results; 5 launches a task that will launch the coroutines, and completes without even waiting for the launching to complete. BTW the type of `workers` is just `Job`, it's not a list of workers.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Number 5 must wait for all the launched coroutines to finish, to quote the docs "A parent coroutine always waits for completion of all its children." I used a plural word for `workers` because it is controlling multiple workers, but I see your point about why it should be singular; it would be clearer.

Comment: When I say that number 4 hangs I mean that CPU usage drops to 0 for several minutes. The main thread waits for the children, as intended, but it seems like the children are also "stuck" some how.

Comment: The parent coroutine doesn't finish until its children finish. But you aren't waiting for the parent coroutine itself. You would need to call `workers.join` to do that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That's really embarrassing, I had `runBlocking { workers.join() }` and accidentally removed it when creating the SO post.

Comment: I'm not reproducing your stated behavior. Both 4 and 5 complete in ~1 second.